# Amazon SQS for windows push notifications

Tags: amazon-sqs

Is it a good idea to use Amazon SQS for push notifications to a windows desktop application ?

Are there any limits to the number of connections ?

Would the number of connected clients affect the pricing, or just the number of messages ?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good match... SQS doesn't limit connections, but when there are multiple consumers listening to a single queue, each message would be delivered to only one of them -- at random -- not all of them.

Comment: cant I create a queue for each device?

Comment: Yes, you could to that.  A queue with zero messages (i.e. the cheapest case) that is long-polled by one consumer at the longest possible interval for continuous real-time delivery (20 sec) generates 3 × 60 × 24 × 30 = 129,600 poll events per month per consumer, approximately $0.07/mo if the client runs all the time.

Comment: You are correct, this would be too expensive. I didn't realize that I pay for empty messages... What about SNS, same pricing?

Comment: Did you found good solution for push notifications to windows desktop application?